# Dijkstras algorithm with priority_queue

Tags: c++, priority-queue, path-finding, dijkstra

I am trying to implement Dijkstra's algorithm. I am using this priority_queue

```
priority_queue<pair<PathInfo,string>,vector<pair<PathInfo,string> >,QueueComp> p;
```

where

```
class QueueComp{
    PathComp* pc;
public:
    QueueComp(PathComp*);
    bool operator ()(const pair<PathInfo,string>&,const pair<PathInfo,string>& );
};
```

is my "Compare" function. The error is that QueueComp **does not have a default constructor** and I am **not permitted to create one**. What can I do to make my code compile? Btw this is the error

```
error: no matching function for call to 'QueueComp::QueueComp()'
```

This is the pathcomp.h

```
class PathComp{
public:
   virtual bool betterThan(const PathInfo& path1,const PathInfo& path2)=0;
};
```

This is the pathcomppl.h

```
#include "pathcomp.h"

class PathCompPL:public PathComp{
public:
virtual bool betterThan(const PathInfo& path1,const PathInfo& path2);
};
```

This is the pathcomppl.cpp

```
#include "pathcomppl.h"

bool PathCompPL::betterThan(const PathInfo& path1,const PathInfo& path2){
    if (path1.getTotalPrice()>path2.getTotalPrice())
        return true;

    if (path1.getTotalPrice()==path2.getTotalPrice() && path1.getTotalLength()>path2.getTotalLength())
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Expanded error message

```
main.cpp: In constructor ‘std::priority_queue<_Tp, _Sequence, _Compare>::priority_queue(const _Compare&, const _Sequence&) [with _Tp = std::pair<PathInfo, std::basic_string<char> >; _Sequence = std::vector<std::pair<PathInfo, std::basic_string<char> > >; _Compare = QueueComp]’:
main.cpp:11:87: error: no matching function for call to ‘QueueComp::QueueComp()’
main.cpp:11:87: note: candidates are:
In file included from main.cpp:5:0:
queuecomp.h:14:5: note: QueueComp::QueueComp(PathComp*)
queuecomp.h:14:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
queuecomp.h:10:7: note: QueueComp::QueueComp(const QueueComp&)
queuecomp.h:10:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Comment: I think your QueueComp type needs a default constructor.

Comment: It seems so.. But I am not alowed to use one.

Comment: you want to store the edge weights in the priority queue so you can always pick the shortest edge

Comment: @Slazer What is the reason that are you not allowed to use a default ctor? Is this a class assignment and the professor gave this as a restriction?

Comment: Also, what is `PathComp`? The "Comp" seems to imply that it is a comparator. Perhaps you can use this directly as the third argument to the `priority_queue` template.

Comment: Would you mind posting a bit more code? It would be nice to see the PathComp class

Comment: Sometimes you can get away with using STL containers on types that don't have default constructors, but you must be very careful never to use any methods in that container which attempt to call the default constructor. In other cases, the STL classes are not well-enough written to allow this at all.

Your error about QueueComp not having a default constructor is probably being triggered by a specific line of code in which you are USING the container. Seeing this line of code is likely to be important.

Comment: You've added a little more information, but I'm guessing that `error: no matching function for call to 'QueueComp::QueueComp()'` is incomplete, and the full error message went on for a good 10-20 lines (at least) beyond that. Sadly, the useful information is in those additional lines (it ought to resemble '...while compiling template instantiation at line X of something.cpp', or similar).

Comment: @AHelps I have added the full error message.

Comment: look at my answer or look at the 33th line of the example on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/priority_queue/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize your priority queue with additional parameter since you have non-default constructor.

`priority_queue<pair<PathInfo,string>,vector<pair<PathInfo,string> >,QueueComp> p(QueueComp(ptrToPathCompObject));`

The additional parameter (`QueueComp(ptrToPathCompObject)`)  should fix your problem.

I am assuming that you have already implemented the `operator()` in QueueComp class.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a default constructor, because you are supposed to initialize the variable called pc. You have this constructor:

```
QueueComp(PathComp*);
```

You have to implement it so that pc is associated to the parameter.

As about your second question: The first element is your next priority, the second element is the set of lower priorities and the third is the queue comparison. I hope this helps you.

Comment: I have the QueueComp(PathComp*_pc) implemented to assign _pc to pc. But how exactly should the third template parameter of the priority_queue look like for it to compile?

Comment: If you call the constructor mentioned in my answer using the new operator, then you will have a QueueComp object. That object will be the third parameter of your priority_queue. So, practice a little. First, try to call the constructor. If you succeeded, assign the result of the constructor call to a QueueComp variable. If you succeeded, then you can use that variable in your priority_queue. Everything is simple if you already know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue is with implementing a proper comparator. One alternative you might consider is to create the comparator like the following

```
struct CompareEdgeWeights : public binary_function<PathInfo*, PathInfo*, bool>
    {
        bool operator()(const PathInfo* left, const PathInfo* right) const
        {
            return left->getEdgeWeight() > right->getEdgeWeight();
        }
    }; // end struct

// Priority queue of node edges
priority_queue<PathInfo*,vector<PathInfo*>,CompareEdgeWeights > * edgePriorityQueue;
```

Have this struct inherit from binary_function and overload the operator (). You can then use this as your comparator for keeping the edges sorted from lowest to highest weight value. Note: you may have to tweak this a bit to conform to your implementation. It is difficult to give a 100% correct suggestion without seeing more of your implementation.

Comment: I have added more implementation to my question.